# click on border button does trigger click when css transform:scale() is active

Tags: css, html, css-transforms

Triggering the click event depends on the value of `transform: scale()`.
When there is a relative big number, it works, but when there is a small one, it does not work properly.

Does anybody know how to fix it?

[Here is my Demo](https://codepen.io/balvin/pen/MVaWLy)

Try to click on the border in order to see it.

```js
document.querySelectorAll("button").forEach((itm)=>{
  itm.addEventListener("click",function(){alert("press")});
})
```

```css
button{cursor:pointer;user-select:none;outline:none;background-color:#c7ffff}
button{border:25px solid red;box-sizing: border-box;}
#b1:active{transform:scale(0.4)}
#b2:active{transform:scale(0.95)}
```

```html
<!-- Click on the border on each one of then-->
<!-- Then click on the center, and it works in both-->
<button id="b1">Click Me</button>
<button id="b2">Click Me x2</button>
```

Comment: It looks like if your mouse up is in the button's current area then it works which makes sense. The click event is called when the mouse button is released and where you release it defines your click.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the div seems to lose the click event as the active button is now too small and therefore the click is no longer inside the button (try the larger button number but click in the bit that turns white and you will see it has the same problem).

> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/click - *The click event is fired when a pointing device button (usually a mouse's primary button) is pressed and released on a single element.*

This means when the button is released, as the mouse is no longer in the button because it was scaled down, the click event for that button won't fire

How about using mousedown to capture the event instead:

```js
document.querySelectorAll("button").forEach((itm) => {
  itm.addEventListener("mousedown", function() {
    console.log("press"); // changed to console so you can see it fire in the snippet as well as the animation taking place (which wuldn't happen with an alert)
  });
})
```

```css
button {
  cursor: pointer;
  user-select: none;
  outline: none;
  background-color: #c7ffff
}

button {
  border: 25px solid red;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#b1:active {
  transform: scale(0.4)
}

#b2:active {
  transform: scale(0.95)
}
```

```html
<!-- Click on the border on each one of then-->
<!-- Then click on the center, and it works in both-->
<button id="b1">Click Me</button>
<button id="b2">Click Me x2</button>
```

Comment: Similar to my deleted answer, it's a little buggy on chrome if an alert is needed but in actual usage, alert is most likely not used

Comment: Yeah if an alert is needed, then this would be no use - unless they pressed enter whilst holding the mouse button down

Comment: My idea is to wrap it with a container and pointer events none the button so the click goes straight to the container. While it works, on chrome when the alert comes and the scale state stays when the alert box is popped lol

Comment: I actually don´t need alert, it was just for explanation porpuse.